# XPath query for the nodes that starts with a particular string and ends with perticular string

Tags: xml, xpath

I am working with legacy code with XML files that I am not allowed to change.

It has nodes like this:

```
<P1StartTest Name="P1 Start Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9520" DataType="6" />
<P2StartTest Name="P2 Start Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9521" DataType="6" />
<P3StartTest Name="P3 Start Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9522" DataType="6" />
<P4StartTest Name="P4 Start Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9523" DataType="6" />
<P5StartTest Name="P5 Start Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9524" DataType="6" />
<P1EndTest Name="P1 End Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9512" DataType="6" />
<P2EndTest Name="P2 End Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9513" DataType="6" />
<P3EndTest Name="P3 End Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9514" DataType="6" />
<P4EndTest Name="P4 End Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9515" DataType="6" />
<P5EndTest Name="P5 End Test" DevID="1" RegType="0" StartAddr="9516" DataType="6" />
```

I need to select either node that start with `P` and end with `StartTest` or sometimes those that end with `EndTest`. I know I have to use `/*[starts-with(name(), 'P')]`  and `/*[ends-with(name(), 'StartTest')]` but how do I combine the both? I am new to XPath.

Comment: /*[starts-with(name(), 'P') and ends-with(name(), 'StartTest')]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can combine them like this (formatted for readability) :

```
/*[
    starts-with(name(), 'P') 
        and 
    (
      ends-with(name(), 'StartTest') 
        or 
      ends-with(name(), 'EndTest')
    )
  ]
```

Above xpath select nodes that starts with `P` and ends with either `StartTest` or `EndTest`. Or if you actually need just one of the two possible end of node name at a time, that would be easier. Example for nodes ending with `StartTest` :

```
/*[
    starts-with(name(), 'P') 
        and 
    ends-with(name(), 'StartTest') 
  ]
```